# fancybox content margin-left

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I see that you can adjust the padding or margin for the content of a fancybox. But for a special case I need to adjust the padding left and right of the content separately.

eg. padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 10px

I tried to edit the css or add a custom css class using the wrapcss property, but the problem is that fancybox seems to calculate its representation ignoring all the css presets.
So if I set margin-left for the .fancybox-image class then the fancybox is not aware that it should be 50 pixel more wide.

do I have to go editing the js or is there another elegant way?

many thanx for your help,
regards,
florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT**********

```
$(".mydiv").fancybox({
        wrapCSS     : 'fwrap'
    });
```

css:

```
.fwrap{
    padding-left:200px;
    margin-right:-100px;
}
```

This leave 200px of padding on the right of the fancybox and then moves it back to the centre, you would have to also apply border, background,etc to sort out styling as you wish

Comment: Hello webweaver! thank you! basically it works with the wrapper-class, but I use the fancybox to show an image. the image should have a margin to the fancybox border. I do not want to move the whole fancybox. If i apply a css to the fancybox-image class (like padding-left:200px;) then the image is just moved out of the lightbox...  i will accept answers in the future :)

Comment: I have updated my answer this should do what you are looking for.